# Programmatically run a script on a sketch file

Tags: automation, sketch-3

Is there a way to programmatically run a sketch plugin on a sketch file from the command line, in any language?

For example: `runCommand --file myfile.sketch --plugin myscript.js`
Would run the plugin `myscript.js` on `myfile.sketch`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This was added in Sketch 43 & above

```
$ sketchtool run

Usage: sketchtool run <bundle> <command> [ --application=<path> | -A <path> ] [ --new-instance{=YES|NO} | --no-new-instance | -N {<YES|NO>} ] [ --wait-for-exit{=YES|NO} | --no-wait-for-exit | -W {<YES|NO>} ] [ --context=<string> | -C <string> ]

Run a command from a plugin, inside Sketch.

Arguments:

    bundle            plugin bundle containing the command to run
    command           the command to run

Options:

    --application     The version of Sketch to launch. If not supplied, the default is to use the version containing sketchtool. (optional).
    --new-instance    Launch a new instance of Sketch, even if one is already running. (optional, defaults to NO).
    --wait-for-exit   Wait for Sketch to exit before returning from this command. (optional, defaults to NO).
    --context         JSON dictionary of values to pass in to the plugin. (optional).
```